# vue.js2 console err is "app.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

the result should be a paragraph contain a name and button to change this name
from "adel" to "mohamed" but it is not working ,not showing any thing in the browser and i have console err is:

> app.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier,
>
> You are running Vue in development mode.
> Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
> See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>vue.js course</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vue-app-one">
    <greeting></greeting>

  </div>

  <div id="vue-app-two">
    <greeting></greeting>


  </div>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js code

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: "<h1>hello {{ name }}. <button v-on:click="chang">change name</button></h1>",
  data(){
    return {
      name:"adel"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    chang: function(){
      this.name = 'mohamed';
    }
  }
});

var one = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app-one'

});

var two = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app-two'

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Just change the double quotation marks used in template to single quotation marks.

> you can't include the same quote mark inside the string if it's being used to contain them

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings

```
template: "<h1>hello {{ name }}. <button v-on:click="chang">change name</button></h1>",
```

to

```
template: "<h1>hello {{ name }}. <button v-on:click='chang'>change name</button></h1>",
```

[jsfiddle that works](https://jsfiddle.net/ra9owLac/)